# allocating two dimensional array one element at a time with realloc in function call I need to allocate memory in Called function

Tags: c

I am trying to allocate individual elements of two dimensional array in function call.

I am getting the pointer reference `char ***a` pointer in function parameter like this  `int substr(char *arr,char c,char ***a,int k)`

But I am getting segFault at realloc line. I am not getting any help from -Wall -Wextra. In this example the function substr allocate for 1 index element of two passed two dimensional array

But I like to allocate memory in called function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

int substr(char *arr, char c, char ***a, int k)
{
    *(a + k) = realloc(a, 5);  
    return 0;
}
    
int main()
{
    char *arr = "this is a new string. check it out";
    char **a;   
    
    a[0] = malloc(5);
    //....some code
    //...
    int count = substr(arr, ' ', &a, 1);    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never allocated any memory for `a`, so you can't assign to `a[0]`.

Comment: `&a` is not a pointer that was returned by `malloc()`, so you can't pass it to `realloc()`.

Comment: Don't use `*(a+k)`, use `a[kj`. And it makes no sense to set an element of an array to the reallocation of the whole array.

Comment: also substr doesn't return int.  none of this code makes any sense, are you trolling us?

Comment: @Barmar `&a is not a pointer that was returned by malloc(), so you can't pass it to realloc()` what are u talking about . I am doing a[0]=malloc(..) so a[0] is &a why I cant I advance to pointer

Comment: @Jasen no I didnt tried realloc before

Comment: `&a` is a pointer to `a`, not the value of `a[0]`.

Comment: `*a` would be the same as `a[0]`.

Comment: @Barmar please clarify realloc works on memory thats already gets allocated with malloc. means I cant use realloc with allocation pointers to pointers ** with new element alocating with realoc and previous elements got allocated with malloc

Comment: You can if the pointer points to to memory that was allocated with `malloc()`.

Comment: If you do `a[0] = malloc(5)` then you can use `realloc(a[0], 6);`

Comment: @Barmar so u are saying in main `a[1]` or `char *ax1`==a[1] has to be allocated with malloc. now clears

Comment: It can also be a null pointer, then `realloc()` acts like `malloc()`. So you can initialize all of `a` with null pointers first.

Comment: @Barmar also how can I pass a[1] address from main which in main is NULL. and allocate it in substr with realloc or do I need malloc for this means realloc cant be used. Can u tell me this please

Comment: @user786 Do you intend for `a` to hold an array of strings? Or just one string?

Comment: @Schwern array of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the conversation in the comments, there's some confusion about `a[0]`. Let's simplify it by working with `char *`.

```
// Declare the variable a which stores a pointer to a char.
char *a;

// Same as *a = 'b'
a[0] = 'b';
```

`a[0]` tries to access the memory `a` points to, same as `*a`. But `a` was never initialized, it points at some random memory you don't have access to, or is out of bounds. Segfault.

`a` has to have memory allocated to it to store 'b'.

```
// `a` points at 5 bytes of memory
// This is the same as `char *a; a = malloc(5)`.
char *a = malloc(5);

// The first byte of malloc'd memory is set to 'b'.
a[0] = 'b';
```

---

Now let's do it with an array of strings.

```
char **a;

a[0] = "some string";
```

Same problem. `a` is uninitialized and points at some random memory. `a[0] = "some string";` tries to dereference `a` and segfaults.

So we need to first allocate space to store the pointers to the strings.

```
// Allocate space for 5 pointers.
// This is the same as `char **a; `a = malloc(...);`
char **a = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 5);

// Dereference the first pointer and have it point to a string.
a[0] = "some string";
```

---

Now to your code. Same thing.

```
char **a = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 5);

// Derefrence the first pointer in a and have it point to 5 bytes of memory.
a[0] = malloc(5);
```

If you want to reallocate the memory in `a[0]` you reallocate `a[0]`, not `a`.

```
// Reallocate the 5 bytes of a[0] and return a pointer to 10 bytes.
// Assign the new pointer to a[0].
a[0] = realloc(a[0], 10);
```

---

If you want to do this in a function, pass in a pointer to the memory work with that. The function doesn't know nor care about the array `a`. Just the string.

```
// Note there's no need to pass in an array index.
void substr(char **dest) {
    // dest is pointer to the pointer in a[0].
    // *dest is the pointer in a[0], the malloc(5).
    // Grow its memory and reassign it back to a[0].
    *dest = realloc(*dest, 10);

    // Assign to a[0] to demonstrate it works.
    strcpy(*dest, "012345678");
}

int main(void) {
    char **a = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 5);

    a[0] = malloc(5);
    substr(&a[0]);
    puts(a[0]);
}
```

---

We can simplify this.

First, since `a` is allocated in main it can use automatic memory. This is memory which is automatically deallocated when the function exits. Because `main` is the first function it will be the last to exit, so any automatic memory in `main` will last for the whole program.

We can't use automatic memory in `substr` because it will be deallocated when `substr` returns.

Second, there's no need to allocate memory to `a[0]` if you're going to immediately `realloc` it. If you give `realloc` a null pointer it will allocate new memory.

```
int main(void) {
    char *a[5];

    a[0] = NULL;

    substr(&a[0]);
    puts(a[0]);
}
```

Finally, we can initialize all the pointers of `a` to NULL using a little syntactic trick.

```
int main(void) {
    // Same as char *a[5] = {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};
    char *a[5] = {NULL};

    substr(&a[0]);
    puts(a[0]);
}
```

Comment: can u please tell what this  `*a[5]` type of pointer is called

Comment: @user786 The technical name for `char *a[5]` is an [array](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm). In this case it's an array of 5 `char *`. I'm pretty sloppy about what I call an "array" in the answer. It is similar to, but subtly different, from `char **a = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 5)`.

Comment: do u mean *a[5] can hold 5 strings from *a[0] to *a[4]

Comment: @user786 Yes. `char a[5]` can hold 5 characters. `char *a[5]` can hold 5 `char *` aka "strings". In both cases, `a` is a pointer.

Comment: @user786 `char *a[5]` can hold from `a[0]` to `a[4]`.

Comment: @user786 For example. `char *a[5]; a[4] = "Basset hounds got long ears";`